# Can qgis2web display rule-based layer style?

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis2web, rule-based

I’ve just made a map that has two layers: one that contains the polygons and  other that contains points. For the last one, I used rule-based symbology where I define the size and colour of the points by the following rule structure:

```
If  “X”(string) = 'a'  and   "Y"(real) <= 0.04   and   "Y" > 0.03
```

[image][image]

The problem is that when I try to export it using Qgis2web the layer points disappear no matter if a use Openlayers or Leaflet.

[image]

I’ve changed the rule-based symbology and used a simple one. That just worked so I deduce that rule-based symbology and qgis2web don’t get well togheter.

[image]

I found here that the rule-based renderer is tied heavily to Qgis expressions, and only a small subset of Qgis expression functions are so far supported in Qgis2web.

I wonder if is there any possible way that I can use my first style layer and not the simple one to export it.

By that I mean, a different rule expression allowed in qgis2web that gives the same result layer,  a different way in qgis to recreate my different point size and colour layer that’s also complatible with the qgis2web pluggin, or even any other pluggin that I can use to export my rule-based symbology layer.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/166330) suggest trying a graduated style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please preselect your layer with "X" = 'a' and export this selection as a new layer. Then go on with your rule-based renderer on this newly created layer which will be supported in qgis2web:
[image]

The ruleset of this working prototype might be similar to yours: [image]

rule based rendering works fine in leaflet and openlayers

Comment: In case someone finds it useful: while I was editing the fields in the layer properties so they didn’t show up in the pop up, I found out I can hide all of them except the field that I used to make the rule. When I hide it, the layer disappears in qgis2web.

Comment: @SofiaR maybe this is helpful for you in the context of hiding many fields in qgis: https://github.com/riccardoklinger/fieldswitcher